# Different way on initialising NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am used to the simple way of initialising NSArray.

```
NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"data1",@"data2",@"data3",nil];
```

I have now come across code in a non arc app where initialisation is done at many place like

```
NSArray *temp;
temp = [@[@"data1",@"data2",@"data3"] retain];
```

Can anyone elaborate the difference between two and if one is better than other.

Thank you

Comment: since the examples were not equal, i am editing the examples.

Comment: In both case u are getting array but difference is that in first your getting empty array and in second your getting array with items(data1,data2,data3). Also init and retain just makes value +1(keeping obj alive) and to relase we -1(that is bring it to 0 in case to release/dealloc). so in somecase some variable are with value -1/0(and are called for use or not dealloc so result in zombie/leaked obj)

Comment: I want to point out that the "new" syntax is not dependent on arc or non-arc. `NSArray *temp = @[@"data1",@"data2",@"data3"];` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is using the new(ish) [Objective-C Literal syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

This literal syntax allows simplified creation of `NSNumber`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects as well as providing subscripting support for arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: Thankyou, so they both are doing the same with different syntax?

Comment: @Nash Yes; you don't *need* to use them, but you will find that you will definitely want to, especially when creating dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is just a shortcut for:

```
+ (instancetype)arrayWithObjects:(id)firstObj,...
```

This

```
@[@"data1",@"data2",@"data3"];
```

will be compiled like:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"data1",@"data2",@"data3",nil];
```

You can't say one is better than the other, they are made for different purposes. The shortcut syntax was invented to create arrays with content faster. You can see the shortcut is less code then the full `arrayWithObjects` example.

There are other shortcuts as well:

```
@{key: object}
```

to create a `NSDictionary`.

```
@YES @NO @value /* like @35 */ @(x + y)
```

to create a `NSNumber`

Comment: Thank you wumm for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement instantiates an `NSArray` object. In practice, you rarely see this code because `NSArray` objects are immutable and it's useless to have an array object with no elements that you can't change. It's more common to have

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

or something similar and then add objects to the array later.

The second case declares a new variable of type `NSArray` and assigns it to an array of three `NSStrings` and then retains this `NSArray` object. This new array is immutable, like before, so it can't be changed. By sending the retain message, the retain count of that object will be incremented and the object will not be deallocated until it is sent a `release`. Without the retain, the object is owned by something else, probably an autorelease pool, in which case it will be deallocated when the method returns.